# CSS3 for HTML5 Legend inside fieldset

Tags: html, css, gradient, fieldset

Can you please suggest CSS to get effect as quoted below (using CSS3 gradient & borders) ?

[image]

Current version of HTML is mentioned below:

```
<section style="margin: 10px;">
<fieldset style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; min-height:150px;">
<legend><b> My Statistics </b> </legend>
<label> <br/> </label>
<label> <br/> </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```css
fieldset {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border: 5px solid #1F497D;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
}

fieldset legend {
    background: #1F497D;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px ;
    font-size: 32px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #ddd;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section style="margin: 10px;">
<fieldset style="min-height:100px;">
<legend><b> My Statistics </b> </legend>
<label> <br/> </label>
<label> <br/> </label>
</fieldset>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/ESkRt/1/)

Answer (score 6):

THERE YOU GO :

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <section style="margin: 10px;">
    <fieldset style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; min-height:150px; border:8px solid #1f497d; background-color:#eeece1;">
    <legend style=" margin-left:20px;background-color:#1f497d; padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px; padding-right:120px; padding-bottom:5px; ; color:white; border-radius:15px; border:8px solid #eeece1; font-size:40px;" ><b> My Statistics </b> </legend>
    <label> <br/> </label>
    <label> <br/> </label>
    </fieldset>
    </body>
    </html>
```